# HP laptop compatibility with HP docking station and a dell monitor

Tags: laptop

can I use an HP laptop and docking station with a dell monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assuming you have a LCD monitor, not a big heavy CRT, then the monitor has a "native resolution". When you first connect, the screen might have distorted dimensions (too narrow or to wide etc). Then change the graphics option by right clicking on the screen and picking "screen resolution". Change that to whatever the monitor's native resolution is.
The only other concern is the plug type. Most things still have a common old school VGA connector or plug that will work with anything. Newer graphics use a digital connection.